# Side DIV not extending 100% in height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a layout that has a side menu bar and then the main content displayed on the right side. The layout and functionality work just fine except for one minor detail -

In some cases, there isnt enough content to fill the entire screen and when that happens the DIV containing the main content does not stretch and fill the remainder of the screen creating a visual difference as seen in the screenshot. I tried manipulating various attributes and putting in dummy content etc but could not find a clean solution. I am hoping someone can help. I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.x

I have included the CSS for the main section, ideally, I would like this white background to fill the screen upto the footer.

```
/*
 * Main content
 */

.main {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #dae3e9;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px -2px #f1f1f3;
}
```

[image: screenshot showing DIV not extending 100%]

I have also created a fiddle with my code, the visual is a little messed up because the output is trapped inside a frame - but [here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/chicagosky/q96uv021/4/) anyway -

Comment: do you use #page-wrapper? if not, try to use it

Comment: the entire page is enclosed in a wrapper div - that works fine. But how do I apply that just for the side DIV? I tried and it didnt work for me

Comment: The bootstrap framework is based on floated elements. Parent elements with `.clearfix` inherit the height of their children but they don't have any actual height of their own. So `height:100%;` does nothing on them or their children. The only way to get the sidebar `height:100%;` working was by removing all occurrences of `float:left;` from `#sidebar`. Then I went through and set `height:100%;` on all of its parent elements up to the body. Only then was the sidebar at `height:100%;` The drawback at that point was the entire rest of the page was completely screwed up. I ran out of commnt space.

Comment: So then I had to mess with `position:absolute;` on the sidebar and `margin-left:16%;` on the main content to make space for the sidebar to show.  But `position:absolute;` also causes the parent elements to collapse their height because it's essentially removing any children that push the page down.  So I got it to work, but I had to completely remove all of what makes bootstrap work. It would have been easier to just do the css from scratch.  So all in all, live with the way bootstrap is setup. Otherwise, I would take the time to completely rework your css without a framework based on floating

Comment: @FactoryAidan - if I understand you correctly, you are stating that there is no solution due to the way bootstrap is setup?

Comment: If that is the message my comments deliver, I will delete them.  I am saying full-height sidebars and floating do not mix. Instead of trying to float my sidebar, I would do this:  `#wrap{position:relative}` `#sidebar{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;}`   `.main{margin-left:16.66666%;}` `.nav.nav-sidebar{height:100%;}`and move my sidebar directly above and outside `.container-fluid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `min-width: 100%`; on your #wrap.
Basically solves the problem.

But i want the footer to still be at bottom etc...
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poi33/q96uv021/9/)

Added:

```
.main::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Suggestion: clean up your code. you don't need that much html code the design your doing. I't will be hell for any one who want to edit or change it at a later stage.

Comment: the markup is available in the fiddle link in my question. However I definitely like your suggestion and think its the right path. Question - you have set the margin-left as 300px - that is because your left side menu has a fixed max-width of 300px. In my case, the left side menu has a width set by bootstrap 'col-md-2'. In such a case, how would I set the margin-left value?

Comment: Now that i have a fiddle to work with i can add my markup give me 5 min.

Comment: 3 hours later... made an update... my head hurts from the size or your html

Comment: Thanks @Persijn - much of the HTML is actually code generated but please do advise if you specifically saw some area for improvement